# How to override apollo client cache policy (cache-first) to make graphql calls?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, evict, in-memory-cache

I have a widget in my react application, where user can refresh to get the newly added tasks in the last hour. I am using **cache-first** policy to cache my data. *But, whenever I am trying to refresh my widget within the same minute, network call is being made for the first click but for subsequent clicks on refresh within the same minute, no network call is being made, instead returning me the cached response.*

**Is there any way to tell Apollo to not to look into cache and make network call while still using cache-first policy**, because I want to minimize the number of request calls to my BE, if user doesn't interact with the widget. So, using cache-first would help me achieve that whenever user navigates between different pages.

I tried evicting the entries in the cache whenever user is refreshing the widget. It worked on *@apollo/client: 3.4.17*, but when I updated my client to the latest i.e., *@apollo/client: 3.5.0* or upper, it started breaking.

Thanks in advance. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You can change the policy on a query by query basis but `cache-first` is always going to look at the cache.